# django fileupload via modelform: form not valid

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a dead simple upload model like so:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    file_field = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')
```

and a corresponding model form like so:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile

        fields = (\
            "file_field", \
                )
```

my view is also dead simple, like so:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print request.POST, request.FILES
        if form.is_valid():
            print "yes, form is valid"
        else:
            print form.errors
    <rest of the view code here..>
```

Now, I get this error all the time:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>file_field<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.    </li></ul></li></ul>
```

Funnily, when I change my model name from `file_field` to just `file` - everything works as expected! Ideallly, I would like to name the field `file_field` and not just `file`.

I do see that the query dict is looking this way:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'xCSgqBdgdKlZ0nUUcTICL1YvYn1k5']}>   <MultiValueDict: {u'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: fileersd.pdf (application/pdf)>]}>
```

How do I tell django that the `file_field` is basically the `file` from query dict above?

So, when I want to bind the form:

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

I would like to able to say that the `file_field` from my models/form is the same as `request.FILES['file']`.. if this makes sense?

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Template looks something like so: http://pastebin.com/pKH025MN at the moment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been helpful if you had stated that you were using dropzone.js, as it looks like the problem is entirely there. Looking at [the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_6) for that library, I see the following:

> If you want another name than `file` you can configure dropzone with the option `paramName`.

so you should be able to simply add `paramName: "file_field"` to your `Dropzone.options.myDropzone` object.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot - which I probably am! I am SO SO sorry about this - I never imagined this was dropzone related! Thanks again. Accepted your answer.